# How to fix Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getState' of undefined?

Tags: reactjs, redux, django-rest-framework, react-redux

I am trying to use React with Redux for the frontend part with django rest framework in the backend. Got the issue getState in Provider tag in App component because of issue in store. And when i try to use the map function in the Words.js, I get error of undefined use of map. And I believe this is because of value of the array is null. Hence to fixed this error of getState.
Got this error even on including the store in Provider of App component when a reducers was not defined.

When I load a  static array it does get rendered properly in the specific component.

This is Redux Store in the filename:store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers'

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const enhancer = composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware));

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    enhancer
);

export default store;
```

The index.js file is below

```
import App from './components/App'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

They action types file types.js using django rest_framework to create the data.

```
export const GET_WORDS = "GET_WORDS";
```

The action file words.js

```
import { GET_WORDS } from "./types";
import axios from 'axios';


export const getWords = () => dispatch => {
    axios.get('/api/words/')
         .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: GET_WORDS,
                payload: res.data
            });
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

combined reducer file

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import words from './words';


export default combineReducers({
    words
});
```

The reducer file word.js

```
import { GET_WORDS } from '../actions/types';[enter image description here][1]

const initialState = {
    words: []
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_WORDS:
            return {
                ...state,
                words: action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

The Component in which the words list will be called: Words.js

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getWords } from "../../../actions/words";


export class Words extends Component {


    static propTypes = {
        words: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
        getWords: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getWords();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                Hi

            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    words: state.words.words
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getWords })(Words);
```

And finally the App component

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import Footer from './Layout/Footer/Footer';
import Header from './Layout/Header/Header';
import WordsDashboard from './Content/Words/WordsDashboard';
import { store } from '../store';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { Words } from './Content/Words/Words';

export class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Fragment>
                    <Header />
                    React Buddy
                    <Words />
                    <Footer />
                </Fragment>
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `initialState` has only `words` prop, so when mapping it to props you have one extra `words` level. Try changing it to:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    words: state.words
});
```

Also you need to use `mapDispatchToProps` for `getWords`, since in your current code you're missing `dispatch` wrapper:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  getWords: () => dispatch(getWords())
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Words);
```

Comment: I tried it, not working, got error `this.props.getWords is not a function` @Clarity

Comment: I added `mapDispatchToProps` step, got the original error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getState' of undefined`,`The above error occurred in the <Provider> component:
    in Provider (created by App)
    in App` @Clarity

Comment: @PrathameshPatil it also seems that you have `export default store;` but then import it as a named import in your app. Change `import { store } from '../store';` to `import store from '../store';`

Comment: and now i am getting `Uncaught TypeError: this.props.getWords is not a function
    at Words.componentDidMount` @Clarity

Comment: Thanks a lot a @Clarity, Solved the issue was the import  `{Words}` changed to `Words` in App component.I kept everything to previous as it is.